# Efficient construction of binomial tree

Tags: binomial-tree, algorithm

The goal is to build a $n$ step binomial tree knowing the end nodal probabibilities $p_1, \dots, p_m$, which correspond to the time $T$ states $S_1, \dots, S_m$. We assume that all paths ending in the same nodes have the same probabibilities and that todays state $S_0$ is known.

Is there some efficient algo out there, which encorporates dividends?

Comment: Do you mean like computational in terms of data-structures?

Comment: Something like that I just want to construct the tree.

Comment: If this is the case, the question is more related to programmers.overflow, because this is really a question for computer scientist.

Comment: Not in my view. A binomial tree is clearly a quantitative tool and its fast construction is a relevant problem for quant finance.

Comment: You know what a binomial tree is and about its applications in finance?

Comment: I know but this question is quite vague, we have two issues here: construction of the tree and the values at the nodes. Efficient tree data structures are more on-topic elsewhere but giving values to the nodes is probably on-topic here. Unfortunately, it's unclear to me what the values should be in this case and how that is linked to dividends in this case. Can you give an example of an (inefficiently) constructed tree and its properties?